# Foundation offcanvas links are not clickable in ios devices

Tags: zurb-foundation

Foundation offcanvas menu links are not working on single tap in ios devices.is there any fix for this?.It is taking multiple taps.

Comment: Can you post some code please either as a jsfiddle or url. Will help us help you. :)